# Get current prerequisite file from a variable for a target in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a directory structure like this:

```
+ root
  + src
    + file1.conf
    + file2.conf
    + ...
    + filen.conf
    + images
      + image1.png
      + image2.png
      + ...
      + imagem.png
```

I want to use `make` to process it like this:

1. `.conf` files are copied from `src/` to `dist/`
2. images are processed by, let's say, `optipng` and are to end up in `dist/images`.

There's some other stuff to do too, but it's analogous to what I'm having trouble with now.

I tried to do this:

```
# SOURCES
CONF=$(wildcard src/*.conf)
IMAGES=$(wildcard src/images/*.png)

# TARGETS
CONF_T=$(CONF:src/%=dist/%)
IMAGES_T=$(IMAGES:src/%=dist/%)

all: $(CONF_T) $(IMAGES_T)

$(CONF_T): $(CONF)
# This always echoes the first .conf file,
# which I guess is correct, but not what I want.
    @echo $<
# So this won't work:
    cp $< $@

$(IMAGES_T): $(IMAGES)
# Same as above
    optipng $< -out $@
```

How to get the current input file to a target that is supplied a file list contained in a variable?

I don't want to hardcode filenames as I don't know how many will there be, ultimately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pattern rule:

```
dist/%.conf: src/%.conf
        @echo Conf: building $@ from $<

dist/images/%.png: src/images/%.png
        @echo Image: building $@ from $<
```